# Circuit modelling​ of a spherical conductor connected to a voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, electromagnetism, capacitance

A hollow conducting sphere is connected to a voltage source like this (below)

[image]

For lumped circuit model of this configuration we need to know about its resistance and capacitance , although resistance of this configuration can be calculated mathematically using
$$R=\frac{\displaystyle \int \limits_{l}\vec E . \vec dl}{\displaystyle \int \limits_{s}\vec J . \vec ds}$$

1. Can we model this configuration as shown in figure (i.e parllel combination of R and C)?

And if answer of above question is Yes then

2. how to calculate  capacitance mathematically so that we can use it in our circuit model.

To me it looks like using Laplace equation and boundary condition , we can find steady state charge on the conductor and then capacitance , but I'm not sure whether this approach is correct or not and worse case might be that we get net charge on the conductor =0 (at steady state) and is it mean C=0?

This all are very confusing , kindly help me on this !

Comment: Could it be that the question is meant as follows: A conductive sphere is charged to a certain potential, with the 'reference potential' 0V being infinitely far away? Imagine the second electrode is also a shell, with infinite radius, concentric with the first shell.

Comment: There are special formulas for cylindrical capacitor and for sphere too. In fact it isn't so weird since actually plate distance is constant (the radius). Look here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html

Comment: @polwel  But isn't your interpretation completely changed the question ?

Comment: I am asking you, because as drawn, the question makes no sense. The voltage source is just shorted.

Comment: @polwel  shorted ? Isn't all the conductor supposed to have some resistance , so how is it shorted?

Comment: So the left half of the shell is positive, and the right half is negatively charged? Then you *are* talking about self capacitance.

Comment: @polwel , I want a circuit model of this configuration so that its behaviour on AC and DC voltage sources can be predicted , so my first thought was to model it as parllel combination of R and C but I'm not sure 1.whether it would be parllel combination of R and C or not 2.and if it would be parllel combination of R and C then how to calculate C

Comment: Is this home work, or an actual real-world problem?

Comment: At a frequency that makes the self-capacitance non-negligible, you're going to need more than a lumped system. Consider trying the same thing on a cube, treated as a single capacitance, vs a waveguide with shorted ends treated as a distributed system.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks for hint , so basically this is a distributed System and we cannot lumped it just like that (using a capacitor) and it is similar to a case where a varying magnetic field is distributed over the area of a ring and we cannot model this using resistor and inductors , but in some cases distributed System can be model (for approximate result) as a lumped circuit (ex - transmission line using self and mutual Inductance) if geometry of distributed System allows it ?